# Feynman Diagrams of Infinite Order

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

It is often the case that infinite objects exhibit properties that are not reflected in any finite object; the behavior of infinite groups are for example fundamentally different in a number of important ways to that of any group of finite order, and there are things that are true of any finite graph that are not true of an infinite graph.

It is easy to see that the same is true of Feynman diagrams: for example, in $\phi^4$ theory, any two-point propagator generates a tower of corrections that must terminate in either a 'snail' diagram or a 'triplet' diagram, but of course an infinite graph can have a tower of corrections that simply goes on forever.

My question is, then: does this go anywhere? Has there been any systematic study of infinite diagrams, especially *not* as limiting processes? I've tried finding results by Google but haven't really gotten anywhere.

Comment: Try ladder diagrams in  Schwinger–Dyson approximation schemes.

Comment: ...for instance, [here](http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~kreimer/wp-content/uploads/SkriptDSE.pdf) look at (8.12), (8.18), (8.19) et seq.

Comment: Is this a resource recommendation question, in that case?

Comment: @NiharKarve  I suppose? It could go either way; I'd just like an answer, I don't particularly care whether the answer is posted in longform on SE or just a link to a paper elsewhere.

Comment: (I'm currently skimming @CosmasZachos' recommendations, though I won't have time to really look at it until the weekend.)